# Recommend Deletion is not always useful in Review page, flag button should be there

Tags: feature-request, flags, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Should be comment” in low quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141704/should-be-comment-in-low-quality-posts)

What to do if you want to recommend an answer to be converted to a comment instead of deleting that altogether?

You will have to go to the question, find that answer and then flag it, adding a flag link in review page itself will be very useful and time saving.

Answer (score 1):

I too would like to see this added.

The flag dialog would need to be different so that you can't flag as "Not an answer" or something similar when you have the option to click "Recommend Deletion".

But like you said, some of the flags still make sense so this should definitely be added.