# Recommend deletion vs flagging?

Tags: discussion, review

I don't understand the relationship between "Recommend Deletion" in /review (Low Quality Posts section) and the normal flagging procedure, if any?

In the low quality section I frequently run into posts that I do not only wish to recommend for deletion but I also consider them a target for flagging. I find no way to do this from the /review page directly, and thus I open the thread separately to flagging the post and then go back to the review page to recommend them for deletion. This let's me believe that either I misuse the tool or that a feature-request is in place. What is the thought behind this:

1. Does a Recommend for deletion automatically flag the post, and thus the flagging is unnecessary?
2. Is this by design and I am not supposed to flag these posts, but rather only recommend them for deletion? This I assume gives better feedback to the user(?).
3. I should both flag and recommend these posts for deletion? In this case I think it would be convenient to be able to do this directly from /review.

If the third alternative is the way to go I'll make this a feature request, as of now its only for guidance.

---

Update: A feature-requestion on the matter is already in place, thus I won't turn this into a new one. But the intention part is still valid as no answers are given to the previous request:
[Recommend Deletion is not always useful in Review page, flag button should be there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139628/recommend-deletion-is-not-always-useful-in-review-page-flag-button-should-be-th)

Comment: I'd say: Don't bother flagging unless it's just outright spam and needs to be deleted immediately. If you "recommend deletion", it bumps it higher in the queue for 20ks to delete it. If you flag it, you add another flag to the moderators massive work queue.

Comment: @Mysticial: Good point, we should not increase the work load for the high reps. But then, to make things clearer and since it will be bumped either way, wouldn't a flag button make sense directly in preview mode?

Comment: The difference is *where* to bump the work load to. 20ks? Or moderators? The moderators are pretty swamped already so it's better to put the load on to the 20ks. (also, 6 "recommend deletion" votes will also delete the post - even without 20k or moderator intervention)

Comment: That, again, makes a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Due to Mystical's comments and answer I have the information that I need. A final thought on the matter. Maybe this could be clarified in the information section of the review site. I'd suggest right under "You can also leave a comment on the answer, ...". Not sure if this is a good idea or not, but I'd believe that other users may make to same hassle for the mods that I (was) doing because of this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pulling in the comments:

- If you select "recommend deletion", it bumps the post higher in the Low Quality Posts queue so that it's more likely to be seen by 20k+ users who have the power to vote for deletion.
- If you flag it, it eventually needs to be cleared by a moderator.

So the difference is *who* you put the load on to. 20ks or moderators? Seeing the number of complaints that we hear from the current mods, they don't need any more flags thrown at them. So I suggest "recommend deletion" unless the post is spam/offensive and needs to be deleted immediately.

Also, when a post gets a total of 6 "recommend deletion" and "delete" votes, it is automatically deleted. So in that case, no work is being put on either 20ks or mods.