# "False" flags waste moderators' time

Tags: discussion, review, flags, low-quality-posts

I run into quite interesting situation:

While I was reviewing *Low Quality Posts* queue, I have noticed [Logic operations implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894600/logic-operations-implementation) question with content as follows (only one line):

> 1's detection in nibble method

I chose `Recommend Close` [option](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1528591) with `not a real question` explanation. That in turn flagged the question on my behalf as `not a real question`.

I checked the question after a while and it turned out that the author updated the question putting that one line content (which made the question really *useless*) and the updates had been rolled back eventually (making the question valuable).

So now my `not a real question` flag will probably be `declined` (and I think it should be) as the question (after the rollback) is *good*.

The flag declination will increase number of declined flags in my account (which does not seems to be that big deal, but for some people might be). But more importantly it may generate large number of "false" flag, which moderators will have to deal with (waste of their time etc.)

My question is: How shall we deal with that kind of situations in the future?

I think it would be beneficial to add *flag rollback* feature; at least for posts which have been edited.

Comment: I think the key thing would just be ensuring that there is some sort of indication in the flag queue that the post has been edited after being flagged, so the person reviewing the flag knows that the problem might have already been addressed.  When this is noticed a lot of mods will mark the flag as helpful, but still do nothing, since the flag was valid at the time it was cast.

Comment: Also discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105453/154510)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A flag like this may never actually get to us. 10k users have access to a queue of close-vote flags that don't show up to moderators. This allows them to take some of the burden off of moderators and vote to close, add a flag to escalate things, or dispute a given flag.

In your case, the flag was automatically marked as helpful by the Community user after the first close vote was cast. We never would have known about it without your Meta question.

Answer (score 2):

Taking from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148341/195761) the following applies to the "Low-Quality" review queue:

> - If you select "recommend deletion", it bumps the post higher in the queue for 20k users who have the power to vote for deletion.
> - If you flag it, it eventually needs to be cleared by a moderator.

So you are not flagging a post when clicking <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> - thus no declined flags for yourself, and no additional load for moderators in that case.

Comment: When I *recommend deletion* a question and give explanation (in my case `not a real question`) the question is flagged automatically on my behalf. So do you recommend not to chose any explanation when recommending deletion?

Comment: @Tom Huh - according to that answer I linked I thought that would not be the case... I will leave that answer here for now, because for some "deletion recommendations" the linked answer seems to be correct...

Comment: Wait, wait - "recommend deletion" and "recommend close" are not the same thing. **Close** recommendations *are* flags, and all close flags generate /close review tasks. The deletion thing is a bit different - while it *kinda* corresponds to "not an answer", there's no flag generated at present.

Comment: @Shog9 That's what I missed. Thanks for clarifying!