# Can VLQ flags on answers raised by >2k rep users count as recommend-deletion votes instead of behaving like regular flags?

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, low-quality-posts

I've crossed 2k rep on a site and I frequently use the VLQ review queues there. However, I've noticed that there's no change in the system's behavior when I raise VLQ flags: my flags are simply sent to the review queue, just like it was when I had 1k. I think that this shouldn't happen for answers: 2k rep users can cast recommend-deletion votes (on answers) through the review queue, so their VLQ/NAA flags should behave in a similar manner, in addition to bumping the post to the review queue.

This is how I believe the system should behave: when I raise VLQ and NAA flags on answers, I should get the option to leave one of those 'From review' comments with a link to that entry in the review queue, along with the recommend-deletion vote. The review log for that post should automatically display that I've said 'recommend deletion'.

For questions in the VLQ queue, the status quo is appropriate. With less than 3k rep, I can only raise flags, not close votes, which is appropriate. And I think that 3k rep users can cast their close votes almost everywhere, so that's not a problem.

Is there a particular reason why the present system doesn't seem to run this way? If not, can this be changed?

<sub>[A post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148340/recommend-deletion-vs-flagging) said that recommend-deletion votes by 2k rep users push the posts to a 20k deletion queue. If that's true, I believe that flags by 2k rep users should send the answer to the 20k queue directly, in addition to being recommend-deletion votes with the special comments</sub>

Comment: For others unfamiliar with these terms, *VLQ* is *very low quality* and *NAA* is *not an answer*.

Comment: Regarding your footnote: there is no such queue, that post was worded in a confusing way. I've edited it to make it more clear.